# cluster points calculation of bigger and smaller distances

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a big set of points in 2 dimensions, and two distances, `d`, and `D`.

I need to find subsets of the points, such that:

- each member of the subset is a distance of less than `d` from all the other members of the subset.
- each member of the subset is a distance of more than `D` from all the points that are not members of the subset.

As you can see there could be several of these subsets, or one, or even none.

I had many ideas, but still cant get one idea run all the way.

Clarifications:

num of points could be hundreds.
distance is in integers - 1,2,3 ... n

My main idea was:

lets say yo have only 4 points.

- I thought first creating a structure that will hold all the pair of points and will tell us true/false if the distance between them is below d or higher that D or none.
  ie:

  ```
   point1     point2       <d     >D
     a          b         true    false
     a          c         false   true
     a          d         false   false
     b          c         false   false
     b          d         true    false
  ```

now with this data I know that each point with a row that has both falses means that it will never be in a cluster.

now with the points that we had left that are possible for cluster,
we will start checking them.

this is the part I stopped...

Comment: Could you tell us about any of the ideas you've had so far?

Comment: Also, could you clarify what "big" and "distance" mean? How many points? Euclidean distance? Have you done any kind of preprocessing to exclude outliers?

Comment: just edited it with my idea @loannis